# Google Dataprep: Save GCS file name as one of the column

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataprep

I have a Dataprep flow configured. The Dataset is a GCS folder (all files from it). Target is BigQuery table.

Since data is coming from multiple files, I want to have filename as of the columns in the resulting data.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** There's now a source metadata reference called $filepath—which, as you would expect, stores the local path to the file in Cloud Storage (starting at the top-level bucket). You can use this in formulas or add it to a new formula column and then do anything you want in additional recipe steps. (If your data source sample was created before this feature, you'll need to generate a new sample in order to see it in the interface)

Full notes for these metadata fields are available here: https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Source-Metadata-References_136155148

---

**Original Answer**

This is not currently possible out of the box.  IF you're manually merging datasets with `UNION`, you could first process them to add a column with the source so that it's then present in the combined output.

If you're bulk-ingesting files, that doesn't help—but there is an open feature request open that you can comment on and/or follow for updates:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74386476